# Is there a way to locate a Google Sheet file from an Apps Script URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

We have lost a very important file that contains several hundreds of questions for our quiz. (We're teachers). However, the app the students take the quiz in still pulls information from this file, so we believe it is not lost. There is code inside the Apps script of the Google sheet that sends randomly chosen questions and send each student a different version of the quiz.

This is the link to the apps script:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwpRjyuBqQF_DuBOVALz1OqiMu37v9v0wC5NahW-e0TCoAbTR27jJl3Lshjrd424Ds/exec

Does anyone know how to reverse engineer this url so we can get the url to the original Google Sheet file?

We tried to paste the code after macros/s/(...)
obviously this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineering the url may not be possible. If you have the Google account from which the script is deployed, all executions of that script is logged here:

https://script.google.com/home/executions?user_access_level=1.2.3.4

If you can get to the script that deployed the webapp, you can access the container directly from it's info page. If the script isn't bound, you'll still be able to get the sheet id from the source code of that script.

Comment: (Assuming the script is actually contained in the same sheet.) And good pointer.

Comment: @Argyll Even without it, once you have the source code, you'll have the id of the file it is accessing - in the code.

Comment: True. That follow-up tip could be a part of the answer maybe?

Answer (score -1):

```
function getFilePathFromIdOrUrl() {
  const resp = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Path from Id or Url", "Enter Id or Url", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
  if (resp.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    const id = resp.getResponseText();
    if (id) {
      var s = id.slice(0, 6);
      if (s != 'https:') {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      } else {
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id.slice(id.indexOf('/d/') + 3, id.indexOf('/edit')));
      }
      var pA = [];
      pA.push(file.getName());
      var folder = file.getParents();
      while (folder.hasNext()) {
        var f = folder.next();
        pA.push(f.getName());
        folder = f.getParents()
      }
      var path = pA.reverse().join(' / ');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(path), 'Path for: ' + file.getName());
      //return path;
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Error: Invalid Input: No id.'), "getFilePathFromId Error")
    }
  }
}
```